# SQL monthly rolling sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to calculate monthly balances of bank accounts from the following postgresql table, containing transactions:

```
# \d transactions
                 View "public.transactions"
 Column |       Type       | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 year   | double precision |           |          | 
 month  | double precision |           |          | 
 bank   | text             |           |          | 
 amount | numeric          |           |          |
```

In "rolling sum" I mean that the sum should contain the sum of all transactions until the end of the given month from the beginning of time, not just all transactions in thegiven month.

I came up with the following query:

```
select 
    a.year, a.month, a.bank, 
    (select sum(b.amount) from transactions b 
     where b.year < a.year 
        or (b.year = a.year and b.month <= a.month)) 
from 
    transactions a 
order by 
    bank, year, month;
```

The problem is that this contains as many rows for each of the months for each banks as many transactions were there. If more, then more, if none, then none.
I would like a query which contains exactly one row for each bank and month for the whole time interval including the first and last transaction.

How to do that?

An example dataset and a query can be found at https://rextester.com/WJP53830 , courtesy of @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: can you also tag the dbms being used?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What do *you* mean by "monthly balance"?  What do *you* mean by "rolling"?  How is a "bank account" represented in the data?

Comment: Most databases provide a window function that will compute cumulative sums. But the details of using it will depend strongly on which DBMS you're using. You should always include the specific database technology on questions involving SQL.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `year` and `month` are better stored as `integer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate a list of months first, then you can outer join your transactions table to that list.

```
with all_years as (
  select y.year, m.month, b.bank
  from generate_series(2010, 2019) as y(year) --<< adjust here for your desired range of years
    cross join generate_series(1,12) as m(month)
    cross join (select distinct bank from transactions) as b(bank)
)
select ay.*, sum(amount) over (partition by ay.bank order by ay.year, ay.month)
from all_years ay
  left join transactions t on (ay.year, ay.month, ay.bank) = (t.year::int, t.month::int, t.bank)
order by bank, year, month;
```

The cross join with all banks is necessary so that the `all_years` CTE will also contain a bank for each month row.

Online example: https://rextester.com/ZZBVM16426

Comment: It still have more rows if there are more than one transactions in a month. See april of 2018 at https://rextester.com/WJP53830

Comment: @ÁrpádMagosányi: then you need to add a `group by`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion in Oracle 10 SQL:

```
select a.year,a.month,a.bank, (select sum(b.amount) from 
(select a.year as year,a.month as month,a.bank as bank,
 sum(a.amount) as amount from transactions c
 group by a.year,a.month,a.bank
) b
where b.year<a.year or (b.year=a.year and b.month<=a.month)) 
from transactions a order by bank, year, month;
```

Comment: OP's title indicates *rolling sum* not simple aggregate sum. And likely the RDBMS is Postgres given the CLI command `\d` and the default schema `"public"`.

Comment: A precise definition of rolling sum being looked for would be helpful.

Comment: edited my answer to compute rolling sum instead of aggregate sum (semantics not checked together with real db; maybe speed improvable)

Comment: ERROR:  column "a.year" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
    LINE 1: select a.year,a.month,a.bank, (select sum(b.amount) from

Answer (score 0):

Consider aggregating all transactions first by bank and month, then run a window `SUM() OVER()` for rolling monthly sum since earliest amount.

```
WITH agg AS (
   SELECT t.year, t.month, t.bank, SUM(t.amount) AS Sum_Amount
   FROM transactions t
   GROUP BY t.year, t.month, t.bank
)

SELECT agg.year, agg.month, agg.bank,
       SUM(agg.Sum_Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY agg.bank ORDER BY agg.year, agg.month) AS rolling_sum
FROM agg
ORDER BY agg.year, agg.month, agg.bank
```

Should you want YTD rolling sums, adjust the `OVER()` clause by adding year to partition:

```
SUM(agg.Sum_Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY agg.bank, agg.year ORDER BY agg.month)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not give you data for those months which does not contain transaction for the given bank.

Comment: Then create a calendar table of all years and months, then left join it to this resultset.